# Invert a Eigen::VectorXd and assign to another Eigen::VectorXd

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, eigen

so I stumbled upon this compilation issue with Eigen. I'm using Eigen 3.3.4 and compiling on Linux with gcc 8.4.0. 
Basically I have a defined class inheriting from `Eigen::VectorXd` which looks like this

```
class dVector : public Eigen::VectorXd {
   public:
    dVector() : Eigen::VectorXd() { setZero(); }
    dVector(int n) : Eigen::VectorXd(n) { setZero(); }
    dVector(const Eigen::VectorXd& v) : Eigen::VectorXd(v) {}
    dVector(const dVector& v) : Eigen::VectorXd(v) {}
    dVector& operator=(const Eigen::VectorXd& v) {
        Eigen::VectorXd::operator=(v);
        return *this;
    }
    dVector& operator=(const dVector& v) {
        Eigen::VectorXd::operator=(v);
        return *this;
    }
   ...
};
```

And then in my code I use it like this:

```
static dVector a(100);
// do something with a
dVector b = -a; // <--- won't compile
dVector b = dVector(-a); <---- compiles
```

The second last line doesn't compile, giving your usual Eigen error message:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'const Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>>::NegativeReturnType'
 (aka 'const CwiseUnaryOp<scalar_opposite_op<double>,
 const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >') to 'dVector'
```

Now the reason why I am really intrigued is that this doesn't compile on Linux, but it compiles on Windows, using MSVC.

I don't really understand why this doesn't compile, my suspicion is that it has something to do with implicit conversions or what the operation `-a` actually returns; maybe it's not a `dVector` but an operation tree. Haven't yet fully grasped what is happening behind the scenes in Eigen.

So then two questions:

1. Why doesn't `dVector b = -a;` compile ?
2. What different thing does the MSVC compiler do that allows it to accept whatever it is that gcc refuses?

Comment: never used eigen, but I know it uses expression templates and thats what you actually see here, so I am not sure if inheriting from their container is a good idea, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator-(dVector)` doesn't exist but `Eigen::VectorXd` is a public base of `dVector` and therefore `Eigen::operator-(Eigen::VectorXd)` is chosen for `-a`.

This operator does not return an `Eigen::VectorXd` but a wrapper type convertible
to `Eigen::VectorXd`. This wrapper type is not convertible to `dVector` as it is needed to be converted to `Eigen::VectorXd` first.

If you try `dVector b = Eigen::VectorXd(-a)` it would work, for the same reason `dVector b = dVector(-a)` works.

Solution:
I would not recommend publicly inherit from `Eigen::VectorXd` use composition instead.

Solution2:
Implement `operator-(dVector)`. Now the compiler will choose this operator instead.

Solution3:
Implement `operator=(Eigen::VectorXd)`. The return type of `Eigen::operator-(Eigen::VectorXd)` is convertible to `Eigen::VectorXd` and can therefore be assigned to `dVector`.

MSVC either has a bug or a language extension to make this compile.